# Is there any way to feed Blu-Rays from a computer/NAS to a remote player?

Tags: video, nas, blu-ray

I would like to serve Blu-Rays from a computer or NAS ("network attached storage") system to multiple televisions in the house. I can have a Blu-Ray player at each TV/monitor/speaker. I just need to get the stream from the NAS to the player (instead of putting the disk in the player physically). Is there any way to do this?

In other words, the guest will use the remote control to access the player (or some kind of selection software), then the software will tell the NAS to stream the Blu-Ray to the player, and the player will show the movie, including the navigation menus.

How can I do this?

Comment: Video DVDs are just a bunch of files on the disc read the correct way; I don't imagine that Blu-Rays would be terribly different. It might mean that you'll need a small computer and VLC on each TV instead of a Blu-Ray player though.

Comment: There are a few ways this can be done. How intelligent are the players? Can you run third party apps on them or on the Tv's? What you are describing is effectively a home media centre and with the correct tools any content you own can be "cast" to various devices. Are your devices able to browse DLNA media servers or otherwise appear as DLNA receivers? What kind of NAS? [Plex](https://www.plex.tv) is a media server which is available for many NAS devices and has clients for many TVs, Android and other media devices. There are tools to move media to a NAS from physical disks...

Answer (score 0):

I have done a fair amount of research and experiments with this, in relation to a Blu-ray project of my own. (8bitMemoirs.com if curious).

What you want doesn't appear to have been possible before - but when Kodi v18 is released in the near future, it will be possible.

Kodi v18 can stream a Blu-ray project - including BD-J (Blu-ray Disc Java) menus, from both a HTTP source and a WebDAV source. Even over the Internet, as I have made possible with 8-bit Memoirs. Obviously it's not very fast (and Kodi v18 is still buggy in regards to BD-J) - but it works, and I expect the final v18 release to have all bugs fixed.

In theory, other software Blu-ray players can also do this, but I haven't had any luck so far. VLC for example can also play Blu-ray with BD-J menus from ISO files or Blu-ray folders. So playing from a HTTP or WebDAV source should be a simple matter of adding a HTTP or WebDAV source to your filesystem, and then play from there.

For Windows, this can be done like this:

```
net use m: http://path.to/mywebdav
```

For Linux, it can be done like this:

```
sudo mount -t davfs http://path.to/mywebdav /mnt/mywebdav/
```

But VLC times out when trying to play this. The developers obviously haven't thought of this scenario yet. I suspect it will work some day in the future though.

Kodi exists for a **lot** of platforms though, including Android. Imagine just installing Kodi on your Android Smart-TV, and then be able to stream Blu-rays. Would be awesome. Unfortunately, BD-J isn't part of the Android version yet, but Kodi developers are discussing the possibility of adding it.